# How to stack function definitions in perl (call them all at once)?

Tags: perl, stack, subroutine

So I want something like:

module0.pl

```
sub fun {
    print "fun $_[0] from 0\n"
}

1
```

module1.pl

```
sub fun {
    print "fun $_[0] from 1\n"
}

1
```

main.pl

```
BEGIN{push @INC, "."};

require "module0.pl";
require "module1.pl";

fun("test")
```

Which will print (in any order - I don't care) :

```
fun test from 0
fun test from 1
```

Is it possible - and what is the most elegant syntax to do it?

Comment: You appear to be creating plugins. There are modules on CPAN to help with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to call a list of subs from various packages (here equally named) ?

One way, using normal packages

```
package Pack1;

use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

sub fun { say "fun $_[0] from ", __PACKAGE__ }

1;
```

The calling program, in the same directory with this package (and its counterpart `Pack2`)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use FindBin qw($RealBin);
use lib $RealBin;

use Pack1;
use Pack2;

for my $packname (qw(Pack1 Pack2)) { 
    MAKENAME: {
        no strict 'refs';
        my $fun_name = $packname . '::' . 'fun';
        $fun_name->("hi") if exists &{$fun_name};
    }   
}
```

I put that scoped `no strict 'refs'` in another block, and name the block, just so; if this is all that is done in the loop there is no need to introduce another scope.<sup>†</sup>  We need the `refs` stricture off for using it as a subroutine reference but then it makes sense to scope the name itself as well.

A few notes

- I don't know why those are `.pl` files which are `require`-ed; they should be packages and I wrote them that way.  Let me know if there is actually a specific (and unbeatable) reason for them to be `require`-ed programs
- Add directories to `@INC` using the [lib pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/lib) with [$FindBin::RealBin](https://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin), not by hacking `@INC`

---

<sup>†</sup> Or copy the coderef

```
for my $packname (qw(Pack1 Pack2)) {
    my $fun = \&{ $packname . '::' . 'fun' };

    $fun->('hi');
}
```

But if we do need to check for existence that should rather be

```
for my $packname (qw(Pack1 Pack2)) {

    my $fun_name = $packname . '::' . 'fun';
    next if not exists &{$fun_name};

    my $fun = \&{$fun_name};

    $fun->('hi');
}
```

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions OK, thanks for attribution -- see the edited (added) comments and let me know if there are hard reasons for `require`-ing `.pl` files (instead of using modules)

Comment: Simplicity - but would it not work with `require`?

Comment: Actually I don't mind using modules as long as I can include them from the same directory. Will this work like that - this `FindBin` - also is it a CPAN or built in?

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions "_would it not work with require_" -- yes, can do that with `require` (I can add code for that).  But if these files have subs then they should be packages, which are properly `use`-d; everything is better and easier this way. The `FindBin` is core, since a very long time ago, and with `use lib ...` you can set it up to find libs wherever you want them, and this is a good way to do it.

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions it just wired way to execute plain Pack1::fun("test"); Pack2::fun("test");

Comment: @gapsf "_just wired way to execute plain Pack1::fun("test"); Pack2::fun("test");_" (you mean "weird" I take it)  -- I don't think we want to have to type in all package names literally for each and every sub? With the "weird" way here a list of packages is entered once, at one place, and so would be the name of subs to run from them.  That was my point.  But I do suggest normally `use`-ing packages with uniquely named subs...

Answer (score 0):

A fairly robust way would be to use a registry for callbacks.

```perl
# main.pl
{
  package MyApp;
  my %callbacks;
  sub register_callback {
    my ( $class, $event, @callbacks ) = @_;
    push @{ $callbacks{$event} ||= [] }, @callbacks;
    return scalar @{ $callbacks{$event} || [] };
  }
  sub run_callbacks {
    my ( $class, $event, @args ) = @_;
    $_->( @args ) for @{ $callbacks{$event} || [] };
    return;
  }
}

BEGIN { push @INC, "." };

require 'module0.pl';
require 'module1.pl';

MyApp->run_callbacks(
  fun     => ( 'test' ),
);
MyApp->run_callbacks(
  boredom => (),
);
```

```perl
# module0.pl
MyApp->register_callback( fun => sub {
    print "fun $_[0] from 0\n"
} );

MyApp->register_callback( boredom => sub {
    print "boredom from 0\n"
} );
```

```perl
# module1.pl
MyApp->register_callback( fun => sub {
    print "fun $_[0] from 1\n"
} );
```